# How to store matrices in separate identifiers

Tags: python-2.7

I am using an for loop to generate matrices based on conditions.
Example : In the first for loop I get [1,2,3]. In the second loop I get [4,5,6] and so on.
When I print the matrices :
[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]...

I would like to store the matrices and then add then based on further conditions.
Like a[] = [1,2,3] b[] = [4,5,6]
a+b
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can zip the two list and can add the two numbers like this `result = [(x+y) for x,y in zip(a,b)]`

Comment: Thanks , the main issue I seem to have is to find a way to store the matrices generated . I have 16 combination matrices generated in the for loop and i need to pick 2 of them only. If there is any other preferable way to reference the two  matrices of the 16 that meet the criteria like length/weight  and then perform the addition , that would be great...